# Calculating Exact Percentage Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im writing an application that automatically adds columns into a div. (Divs inside Div). The issue comes with odd ball column widths such as 6. 6 can't equally divide into 100% so my solution was to find the remainder after the decimal and add it to the last column.

For some reason, when I calculate the remainder it is 0.3999999999999915 instead of .4

Here is my jQuery

```
var numCol = $('.column').length,
        colWid = Math.floor((100 / numCol) * 10) / 10,
        numRem = 100 - (colWid * numCol);

    $('.column').width(colWid + '%');
    $('.column:last-child').width(colWid + numRem + "%");

    alert(numRem);
```

Should I be using Math.round? Im worried that this may cause some issues later on.

---

Solved with

```
var numCol = $('.column').length,
        colWid = Math.floor((100 / numCol) * 1000) / 1000,
        numRem = (100 - (colWid * numCol)).toFixed(3);

    $('.column').width(colWid + '%');
    $('.column:last-child').width(Number(numRem)+ colWid +'%');
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an error. It is just how floating point is designed.
You can use number.toFixed() to convert float to string

toFixed accepts a number of digits as a parameter.

Comment: Now it is combining values ex: 33.33.11

Answer (score 0):

Apply Math.floor function to whole calulation and numCol must be an integer or have to convert into an integer.

```
colWid = Math.floor(((100 / numCol) * 10) / 10)
```

Instead of

```
colWid = Math.floor((100 / numCol) * 10) / 10
```

Comment: That turns the var into a whole number. The idea was to spread it out equally over each column until it couldn't divide anymore.